# How to upgrade "ChangeNotifierProxyProvider" to new version in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, syntax, proxy, upgrade, provider

I got this code:

```
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Auth(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
      builder: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
        auth.token,
        auth.userId,
        previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
      ),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Cart(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
      builder: (ctx, auth, previousOrders) => Orders(
        auth.token,
        auth.userId,
        previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders,
      ),
    ),
  ],
```

But it seems it's deprecated and gets the following errors at the lines with `hangeNotifierProxyProvider`:

```
The parameter 'create' is required.
The parameter 'update' is required.
```

I don't know how to upgrade this part of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code and seems it works, but I'm not still sure if I did it right?

```
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Auth(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
      create: (ctx) => Products('', '', []),
      update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
        auth.token,
        auth.userId,
        previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
      ),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Cart(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
      create: (ctx) => Orders('', '', []),
      update: (ctx, auth, previousOrders) => Orders(
        auth.token,
        auth.userId,
        previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders,
      ),
    ),
  ],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).